# Return a single row with the maximum value

Tags: mysql

I have a table with some fields (trackid, artist, countview), and I need to return only the row with the maximum `countview` value.

Tried

```
SELECT trackid, artist, MAX(countview) FROM tracklist
```

but I think I should put on HAVING?

Comment: If you know (or think) you should use HAVING, how hard is it to look up its syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT trackid, artist, countview
FROM tracklist 
ORDER BY countview DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT trackid, artist FROM tracklist WHERE countview = (SELECT MAX(countview) FROM tracklist)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT trackid, artist, countview FROM tracklist ORDER BY countview DESC LIMIT 1

SELECT trackid, artist, countview FROM tracklist WHERE countview =(SELECT max(countview) FROM tracklist)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tracklist 
WHERE countview = (SELECT MAX(countview) FROM tracklist)
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT trackid, artist, MAX(countview) FROM tracklist GROUP BY trackid, artist

Comment: This wouldn't give the requested result, and would only be useful if one combination of trackid,artist had multiple different values for countview.